# How to use my browser as a pdf viewer on LaTeXTools?

Tags: viewers, sublime-text, latextools

I hope this is the right community to ask this question. (If not, please direct me to the correct community.)

I was wondering how I can configure LaTeXTools on Sublime Text 3 so that the compiled PDF shows in my browser (say, in Chrome) rather than a PDF viewer (I use Skim on my MacOS).

I want to switch to using a browser because I like to have everything in one place (all the pdfs I have opened, my browser tabs, etc.)

Extra question: I would also like the browser to refresh when I hit `command B` in Sublime Text so that the pdf becomes updated, just as in an ordinary pdf viewer.